# How to pass Context from form view to variable on python?

Tags: odoo-16

I have bank statement form view like this :

```
<record id="view_account_bank_statement_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.bank.statement.form</field>
        <field name="model">account.bank.statement</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Account Bank Statement">
            <header>
            </header>
            <sheet>
                <div class="oe_title">
                    <h1>
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <group>
                    <field name="date"/>
                    <field name="journal_id"  context="{'journal_id':7}"/>
                    <field name="new_journal_id" context="{'new_journal_id': new_journal_id}"/>
                    <field name="balance_start" context="{'balance_start':balance_start}"/>
                    <field name="balance_end"/>
                    <field name="balance_end_real"/>
                </group>
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Statement Line" name="line_ids">
                        <field name="line_ids">
                            <tree string="Bank Statement Lines" editable="bottom" context="{'o2m_active_model': 'account.bank.statement',
                            'journal_id': 7}">
                                <field name="date" context="{'test': 1}"/>
                                <field name="state"/>
                                <field name="payment_ref"/>
                                <field name="ref" widget="handle"/>
                                <field name="partner_id"/>
                                <field name="amount"/>
                                <field name="suitable_journal_ids"/>
                                <field name="currency_id"/>
                                <field name="journal_id"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

But when I tried to get the context in python with this code:

```
context = self.env.context
parent_journal_id = context.get('parent_journal_id',False)
journal_id = context.get('journal_id',False)
```

It was always return none. I Had some experience in OpenERP 7 but new in Odoo 16 Community Edition.

Im digging information, the problem (I think) is because Odoo 16 use frozendict type, while in openerp7 still using normal dictionary. Is there any way I can update the context? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try putting the context inside the field tag instead of tree. e.g

```
<field name="line_ids" context="{'parent_journal_id': parent.journal_id}">
```

something like that.. I'm sure you can use `parent` variable to access field values of its o2m parent.